# How to split a set into two disjoint subsets in a special way?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Suppose $S$ is a finite set (the number of its members is not large).
The set $\Sigma=\{s_1, \ldots, s_N\}$ is a set of subsets of $S$, i. e. $s_i \in S$.

Is it possible to split $S$ into disjoint parts $S_1$ and $S_2$ that for any $i$: $s_i \cap S_1 \not= \emptyset$ and $s_i \cap S_2 \not= \emptyset$ (in other words, any $s_i$ is composed from both $S_1$ and $S_2$)?

I seek an algorithm enabling to decide if such division is possible (or not).

Comment: Is there any restriction on the elements of $\Sigma$? If not, the answer is no (in general)—for example, if $|S| \ge 2$ and $\Sigma$ contains at least two singletons, no such partition of $S$ exists.

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is s *set of* subsets, then I'd rather expect $s_i\subseteq S$ instead of $s_i\in S$

Comment: The task is trivially unsolvable if any of the $s_i$ is empty or a singleton.

Comment: If your subsets happen to all be of size $2$, this is the same as $2$-coloring the graph defined by the edges $\Sigma$, which can be solved by a greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [set splitting problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_splitting_problem).

You can use integer linear programming. For each $j\in S$, let binary decision variable $x_j$ indicate whether element $j$ is in $S_1$.  The constraints are $1\le \sum_{j\in s_i} x_j \le |s_i|-1$ for all $i$.  If the problem is feasible, the values of $x$ determine such a bipartition. If the problem is infeasible, then no such bipartition exists.

Answer (score 0):

Not in general, to give an example: Let $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and let $s_{1}=\{1,2\},\ s_{2}=\{1,3\}$ and $s_{3}=\{2,3\}$.

Then any non-empty disjoint pair $S_{1},S_{2}\subset S$ such that $S_{1}\cup S_{2}=S$ does not satisfy $s_{i}\cap S_{1}\neq\emptyset$ and $s_{i}\cap S_{2}\neq\emptyset$ for all $i$.

Comment: Dear friends, I should give more exact statement of the problem.
Given above mention conditions, is it possible to split the set $S$ in such a way?
It's obvious, that in some cases the answer is No, in some -- Yes.
The algorithm that return the answer is required.

Answer (score 0):

@FlorisClaassens example shows, I think $\Sigma$ is also a partition of $S$, not an arbitrary set of subsets of $S$!

In that case as @CliveNewstead said, you must to have no singleton.

Now if two above condition hold, the answer is actually **Yes**. In fact you can split any $s_i$ to two partition $s_i \cap S_1 \ \& \ s_i \cap S_2$. It likes an algorithm for smalling partitions.