# Splitting a set into subsets

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have a set of size 12 and we want to split it into two subsets of size 6 (and it does not matter, which of the subsets is the first and which is the second). How many ways do we have to do it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398869/how-to-split-a-set-into-two-disjoint-subsets-in-a-special-way

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tfrac{1}{2}{12 \choose 6}$ - you chose 6 out of 12 for the first set. Each such partition is counted twice, so you divide by 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have a set with $12$ elements, let's call it $A$ and you want to split the set into 2: $A_1$ and $A_2$.

$A_1$ will have 6 elements, so let's write: $A_1=\{\_ \ ,\_ \ ,\_\ ,\_\ ,\_ \ ,\_\}$. In the first $\_$ you have 12 elements to chose from, in the second 11, in the third 10 and so on... So we get: $12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot9\cdot8\cdot7$.

If $A_2$ will have the opposite elements we chose in $A_1$, so each combination is counted twice (if $A_1=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ then $A_2=\{7,8,9,10,11,12\}$, but when $A_1=\{7,8,9,10,11,12\}$ then $A_2=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ so half of the combinations will be repeated ones.) So our final result will be: $\frac{1}{2}(12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10 \cdot9\cdot8\cdot7)$